# Do not understand Java MouseInfo code in Greenfoot

Tags: java, greenfoot

I don't quite get how this bit of code works. I understand the outcome (to add a new object using the mouse coordinates), but can you explain to me how the lines beginning with 'MouseInfo...' and 'addObject..' work? Is a new MouseInfo object created for each click event called 'mouse'?

```
public void act() 
{
    // Add your action code here.
    if( Greenfoot.mouseClicked(this)) {
        MouseInfo mouse = Greenfoot.getMouseInfo();
        addObject( new Frog(), mouse.getX(), mouse.getY());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mark the question as answered if you found the info you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke `Greenfoot.getMouseInfo()`  you receive a `MouseInfo` object from the `Greenfoot` class. It could be a new Object for every click or one that gets reused and updated as the user clicks.

The `MouseInfo` object has the methods `getX()` and `getY()` which return the coordinates of the click. Finally the `addObject` method adds a new frog at the specified position.